# How to continue adding values after changing if stetment javascript

Tags: javascript, function, timer

I made a timer that calculates time spent multiplied by the price, now we have to make a "happy hour", where at certain times price-per-second to change, now the problem is that when price is changed the price and the total amount are auto change with new value in order to force javascript to continue adding new price and not changes  new amount just continue to add. thank you sry for my bad English.

```
function timedCount() { 

var date = new Date();
if (date.getHours() > 3 && date.getHours() < 8)
{
    PricePeerSec = 100;
} else {
    PricePeerSec = 333;
} 
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.background="#FFFFCC";
    document.getElementById('txt').value = seconds;
    document.getElementById('din').value = totalPrice;
    Seconds = Seconds + 1;
    totalPrice = Seconds * PricePeerSecond;
    timer = setTimeout("timedCount()", 1000);
}
```

Input box where seconds goes have id "txt"
And input box where total goes have id "din"

Comment: Can you rename your variables to reflect their real meaning?

Comment: We don't have context of that function, but as it stands, `z`, `c`, `d` and `t` are all global variables whose names could conflict with other uses.

Comment: You question is not very clear. What problem do you have with this code? What do you expect it to do? What does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you need something like this:

```
var secs = 0,
    totalPrice = 0,
    timer;

function timedCount() {
    var hour = new Date().getHours(),
        price = (hour > 3 && hour < 8) ? 111 : 333;
    secs += 1;
    totalPrice += price;
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.background="#FFFFCC";
    document.getElementById('txt').value = secs;
    document.getElementById('din').value = totalPrice;
    timer = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PG2M/).

Comment: hi, thank you for help, i did it already but with different aproach... :)